Do projective representations imply a relationship between spin and normalization of single-particle states?
I was reading about how we take projective representations of the Lorentz group because there is no physical meaning to multiplying a single-particle state globally by any complex number.  If you multiply it by a real number you're un-normalizing it, which is meaningless, because after all it's really just a ray in Hilbert space; and it's also meaningless to apply a global complex phase shift.
We then transfer our indifference about complex scale factors over to the actual group structure of the transformations themselves, which I'll confess feels to me like a subtle sleight of hand.  But I don't want to get sidetracked, there's something I'm even more curious about.
In particular, if I've got it right, it is when we allow for complex phases to appear in the group structure that the spin group shows up to the party, and spinors, i.e. fermions, make their appearance.
But again, in principle, the idea of a projective representation is that it respects the entire field of complex numbers, that is, it resolves the ambiguity about both the phase and norm of the state.  And although a complex number can be decomposed into phase and norm, it doesn't have to be; it is a whole entity in its own right.  So that leaves me wondering, is the existence of spin-$\frac12$ particles somehow intimately tied to the fact that single-particle states are normalized?  What can we say about their relationship?
